# Blob or Upload?

Tags: php, mysql, file-upload, blob

i do not have an issue with disk space and with my web app only 30 images will be loaded at once, issue is there is a 3 second ajax for these images so they are either.

A. mysql query every 3 seconds per image. (per viewer)

B. Use Uploaded Photos.

At the moment I am assuming an uploaded photo is the best but I am not the pro at these things so I wanted a second opinion. Thanks.

Comment: You might want to start from the beginning and tell us what you're doing instead of what you don't have problems with.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm sorry, your question is not very clear.

If you're worried about multiple MySQL queries, that is not an issue, assuming your are not running mulitple queries around the clock.

On my web apps, a single page load will query the database 10 to 50 times. But that is nothing for a good host.

Edit: generally speaking, it's faster to store the image files on the webserver, rather than storing them as blobs in the database; they will be delivered by the server which is optimized for it. Instead store the image filenames in your database and reference them that way.

Comment: I thought Querys have something to do with bandwidth, i guess im wrong?

Comment: A query, or a command sent to and run by your database, consumes a negligible amount of bandwidth. Uploading images DOES consume your bandwidth, and it can really add up, depending on the size of the images, and the quantity of uploads or downloads.